# Why can't I hit this UNC path from my Windows Service?

Tags: c#, networking, service, unc

I'm working on file replication service in C#. The service works perfectly in an environment where I have access to the user space; however, when I run it as a service I start encountering errors.

There is a lot of information out on accessing UNC shares in this scenario, but after pursuing what seemed to be the most likely solution, I've still come up short.

In my 'faulty' environment, the service is running as the 'administrator' account, and I've taken a couple of approaches; both using a mapped network drive, and a specific UNC share, and end up with the same outcome in both circumstances.

My constructor contains the logic for detection of whether or not the file exists, so it should be the only relevant piece in this equation;

```
    public FileMonitor(String TargetPath)
        : base()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TargetPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot instantiate FilesystemMonitor. TargetPath was not provided or is null.");
        }
        else
        {
            this.FileCache = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

            if (Directory.Exists(TargetPath))
            {
                this.TargetDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(TargetPath);
                return;
            }
            else if (File.Exists(TargetPath))
            {
                this.TargetFile = new FileInfo(TargetPath);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (TargetPath.StartsWith("\\\\"))
                {
                    FileInfo Finfo = new FileInfo(TargetPath);

                    UNCHandler.connectToRemote(Finfo.DirectoryName, "administrator", "password");

                    if (Directory.Exists(TargetPath))
                    {
                        this.TargetDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(TargetPath);
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (File.Exists(TargetPath))
                    {
                        this.TargetFile = new FileInfo(TargetPath);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot instantiate FileMonitor for file that does not exist at " + TargetPath + ".");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot instantiate FileMonitor for file that does not exist at " + TargetPath + ".");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The only exception to my last statement is the potential necessity of knowing what my UNCHandler class does - but to quell that storm, it is an exact rip from the answer [Found Here](http://lookfwd.doitforme.gr/blog/media/PinvokeWindowsNetworking.cs)

To be clear - the issue here is that the File.Exists and Directory.Exists checks fail, even after an attempt to connect to the remote system.

My error log hands me back the following; 'system|ReadConfiguration:Cannot instantiate FileMonitor for file that does not exist at Z:.' - which is effectively the exception that I generate in the above constructor.

I've tried using a variety of methods to reach my 'source'; including using a UNC share and a mapped drive, only to yield no difference in results.

I took an answers advice and ran microsoft's Process Monitor in an attempt to look further into this, but have yet to find any information in this venue that will help me. Under my process, I get dozens of SUCCESS's until I attempt to reach the share - at which point the only indicative results are a 'NAME NOT FOUND' against a CreateFile operation, and a 'FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS' moments later against a 'CreateFileMapping' call.

The process is running as the local systems Administrator account, and in my 'user space' I have a mapped drive to the same location I am trying to reach, that I can manipulate fully.

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting? Have you tried running ProcessMonitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see what is happening?  Are you running as the local administrator for that computer?  Does that local administrator account actually have access to the share in question?
Have you tried using psexec (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to run a command shell as that user and see if you actually have access to that share?

Comment: +1. Likely permissions issue - tools are the right one to figure out. If you rephrase questions as statements it would look more like an answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov started by writing a comment and then decided that it was too long and too good and switched to the answer :)

Comment: I'm not getting any errors - the 'Directory.Exists' and 'File.Exists' methods are returning false. In my error log I end up with the exception that I generate in the above code; I.E. 'Cannot instantiate FileMonitor for file that does not exist at \\IPADDRESS\D$\.' I also know that I have valid permission to access the the filesystem, as I already have a mapped drive to the directory ( and can manipulate the filesystem ).

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 processmonitor

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 - "service is running as the 'administrator'" is most likely not your account... You need to check what permissions that administrator account has.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 it will show you what file is actually being access and who the process is running as.

Comment: Right... I've since explored the concept and found some interesting information - but I believe I can digress that this is Not a permissions issue. Before my service processes threads exit, there is a call to 'CreateFileMapping' that returns a result of 'SUCCESS'. All permissions on the share ( on the remote computer ) have been granted.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 I am running into this exact same issue how did you get it to work?